# how to make a button when you click it image change to another one

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i have 10 images and i want to make button when i clikc it the image change to the next one and i click again it change to the 3rd one etc.. till 10 how can i do it in kotlin?

Comment: Please explore documentation https://developer.android.com/, your question is too general.

Comment: bro i search in every site and in youtube and nothing help thats why im asking here

Comment: You need to add more detail to make this answerable. For example, where are these images located (on the web, in files, as resources in your app bundle)? How are you displaying them? Is the list of images something you know beforehand and it's always the same? Start by showing an image, and adding a button. Then if you can't figure it out, post the code you have and ask a concrete question about it.

Comment: buttontwo.setOnClickListener {
            if (images == 0) {
                imagetwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.duck)
                images = 1
            } else if (images == 1){
                imagetwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.sun)
                images = 2
            } else if (images == 2)
                imagetwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.doctor)

        }

Comment: i think i got it all my images come from R.drawable and i want to put them in one imageview in xml ( sorry my english bad ) i hope you understand is this code good its work